# How do I find the piece of this text string in javascript?

Tags: regex

I'm using jQuery and have retrieved a string containing all the classes of an element like this:

```
var classes = $('[class^="menu-icon-"]').attr('class');
```

The string prints something like this: "foo menu-icon-icon-name bar"

How can find out what the "icon-name" part in the string is, whatever it may be?

It will always be with a class formatted as "menu-icon-{icon-name-here}" among whatever other classes the element may contain.

Comment: Can you show us an attempt at what you've tried?

Comment: $('[class^="menu-icon-"]').each(function(i,o){ $(o).attr('class'); }); then use indexOf to find your string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in all cases-

```
var menuname = classes.substr(classes.indexOf("menu-icon") + 10).split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is absolutely perfect. I tried it in every scenario I could think of and worked in all cases, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have one div's classes as a string

```
var class = "foo menu-icon-icon-name bar"
```

if you are certain that there will always be a space after "" you should be able to do something like

```
var name = class.match(/menu-icon-(.*) /)[1];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's awesome. Would there be a solution if I didn't know there would always be a space at the end?

Comment: It also appears that if I have more classes than just one class after the menu-icon-{whatever} it doesn't work either. This is the real example I'm working with:

`var string = 'menu-icon-home menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1615';
var name = string.match(/menu-icon-(.*) /)[1];`

In this case, it ends up as: "home menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"